# Automating keystrokes via vnc

Tags: bash, vnc

I have a set of shell scripts which configure various machines via ssh. As a temporary workaround to some network problems, I'd like to send a single command `echo foo > bar` via VNC to get the network working for a particular fringe case, but am having a little trouble finding a simple solution.

Is this something that can be accomplished easily? I did find a python package called `vncdotool` but after some pip issues, I abandoned that path as to not waste hours troubleshooting an issue spawned from an issue.

EDIT: I should add that these are VM's running on a VMWare ESXi system

Comment: Why not transfer those files using scp ?

Comment: Network doesn't work. They are VM's so I can always access them via VNC